# CCLabelBMFont with .tga?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am developing cocos2d game. Where I am trying to create CCLabelBMFont. In resource I have .fnt file and .tga file. Is it possible to make CCLabelBMFont with .fnt file and .tga (instead of png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can only use PNG, JPG or PVR image files. Just about any image program will be able to convert an image from TGA to PNG in a second.